# Log4J 2.8.1 using PropertiesConfigurationBuilder to load properties from strings

Tags: log4j2

I am looking for a way to prepare configuration and initialize a logger context from hard coded properties string; not from properties file. Following is the code that seems to be working; it logs the lines that I am expecting as per the log level. However there are few things which I am not able to figure out. I have asked them as inline questions in the code itself; appreciate inputs on the same.

Thanks in advance.

-WinCPP

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("status", "TRACE");

        properties.setProperty("appenders", "CONSOLE");

        properties.setProperty("appender.CONSOLE.name", "ConsoleAppender");
        properties.setProperty("appender.CONSOLE.type", "Console");
        properties.setProperty("appender.CONSOLE.layout.type", "PatternLayout");
        properties.setProperty("appender.CONSOLE.layout.pattern", "%r [%t] %p %c %notEmpty{%x }- %m%n");

        properties.setProperty("rootLogger.level", "ALL");
        properties.setProperty("rootLogger.appenderRefs", "theConsoleRef");
        properties.setProperty("rootLogger.appenderRef.theConsoleRef.ref", "ConsoleAppender");

        PropertiesConfigurationBuilder pcb = new PropertiesConfigurationBuilder();

        // Q1: Is it correct to call setConfigurationSource with 'null'?
        pcb.setConfigurationSource(null).setRootProperties(properties);
        PropertiesConfiguration config = pcb.build();
        Configurator.initialize(config);

        /* Q2: How do I do the setStatusLevel e.g. the 2nd line in commented
           code below, when I am using property route to initialize the logger? Even
           if I set rootLogger.level to 'ALL' (above code), I still do not see
           Log4j 2.x internal messages. I can see those if I use ConfigurationBuilder, though.

        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setStatusLevel(Level.TRACE);

        EDIT: Add "properties.setProperty("status", "TRACE");"

        */

        Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();

        logger.error("This is error message");
        logger.info("This is info message");
        logger.trace("This is trace message");
}
```

Comment: I got answer for the question Q2. The solution is to set the 'status' property as per the following [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties). I have added following line to the question text.

`properties.setProperty("status", "TRACE");`

Q1 still remains.